# Enable KVM on GitHub Actions for private repository

Tags: android, github-actions, kvm

I need to run an Android emulator in my GitHub Actions workflow for integration testing. As I read [here](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/android-emulator-runner) this can be done with this step:

```
- name: Enable KVM
  run: |
    echo 'KERNEL=="kvm", GROUP="kvm", MODE="0666", OPTIONS+="static_node=kvm"' | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/99-kvm4all.rules
    sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
    sudo udevadm trigger --name-match=kvm
```

This fails with `Failed to open the device 'kvm': No such file or directory` and the above link also says this is only available for free for public repos, but we have GitHub Enterprise so should I be able to enable it for our private repos somehow?

How can I enable KVM on our private repos?